# Rails link_to approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So I have the following within a view:

```
= link_to 'link_name', { controller: 'controller_name', action: 'create' }, class: 'class', method: :post
```

Thoughts as to where I might be going wrong in terms ensuring that a `POST` request is placed (sending a `GET` request)?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 #[...]
 resources :controller_name
 #[...]
end
```

Comment: Try this `= link_to 'link_name', { controller: 'controller_name', action: 'create' , method: :post}, { class: 'class'}`

Comment: @sontya post revised!

Comment: This looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/29155523/597358. Have you included the unobtrusive JavaScript driver?